# XIAdapter Error in Soap UI

Tags: web-services, soapui

I'm trying to submit the request and get the response in SOAP UI but getting the following error.

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP:Body>
      <SOAP:Fault>
          <faultcode>SOAP:Server</faultcode>
          <faultstring>Server Error</faultstring>
          <detail>
             <s:SystemError xmlns:s="http://sap.com/xi/WebService/xi2.0">
                <context>XIAdapter</context>
                <code>ADAPTER.JAVA_EXCEPTION</code>
                <text>See log trace with id: n/a</text>
              </s:SystemError>
          </detail>
      </SOAP:Fault>
   </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

The request i'm sending is

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:seg="http://intel.com/xi/Intel-MDM/Project/Segment">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <seg:ListSegment_Request>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <SegmentName></SegmentName>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <StatusCode></StatusCode>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <PendingInd></PendingInd>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ChangeDateFrom></ChangeDateFrom>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ChangeTimeFrom></ChangeTimeFrom>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ChangeDateTo></ChangeDateTo>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ChangeTimeTo></ChangeTimeTo>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <List>
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <Item>
           <SegmentIdentifier>?</SegmentIdentifier>
        </Item>
     </List>
    </seg:ListSegment_Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is the issue with server or SOapUI or am i missing something here?